# Test whether it is a JSONArray or JSONObject when it can be both

Tags: java, json

[JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVnIu.png)

I have a JSON file where value can either be an object or an array. I have written the following code in Java for reading the file.

```
public static void getInput() throws IOException, ParseException{


//creates a new JSON parser object.
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

File file = new File("my file"); 

Object ob = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));

JSONObject job = (JSONObject) ob;

JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) job.get("declaration-list");



for (Object o : ja){

    JSONObject declared_variable = (JSONObject) o;

    JSONObject value = (JSONObject) o;

    String dv = (String) declared_variable.get("declared-variable");
    long v = (long) value.get("value");


}
```

I would like to get operator and arguments from value if it is a JSONArray, but there are instances where value is a JSONObject. How do i test for this?

Answer (score 1):

Although there may be better ways but simply use of `instanceof` can be helpful.

```
Object o ... 
 if( o instanceof JSONObject) {
       processJSONObject((JSONObject)o);
 } else if (o instanceof JSONArray){
       processJSONArray((JSONArray)o);
 } else {
      // Invalid object type handling 
}
```